# Python: Converting time units on a DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, timedelta

guys. I've made an arithmetical operation between two Datetime columns in a DataFrame, that produced the following results:

```
28 days 15:16:53
7 days 13:12:31
334 days 01:04:46.123501
376 days 09:45:21.546136
-1 days +23:56:21.954750
-1 days +23:59:40.110747
```

When I tried putting this into a numpy array, it turned to nanosseconds:

```
array([ 2474213000000000,   652351000000000, 28861486123501000, ...,
       -218045250000,      -19889253000,   673953486963000],
  dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
```

And when I tried to plot an histogram using this array, I've got the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I need to turn this into a more manageable time unit, so that I can make an array and then the histogram. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is dtype='timedelta64[ns]'  .(hist) function uses some function which couldn't deal with timedelta64[ns]' ( ex : isnan ) so simply you can change the type to ( dtype = 'float64' )

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a Series of Timedelta (let us call it `delta`)

```
0           28 days 15:16:53
1            7 days 13:12:31
2   334 days 01:04:46.123501
3   376 days 09:45:21.546136
4   -1 days +23:56:21.954750
5   -1 days +23:59:40.110747
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

You can convert it easily into a Series of floating point days:

```
delta.astype('int64')/(24*60*60*1000000000)
```

gives:

```
0     28.636725
1      7.550359
2    334.044978
3    376.406499
4     -0.002524
5     -0.000230
dtype: float64
```

Just remove `24*` to have floating point hours, same for minutes or seconds